# Duvida com "pivot" ORACLE

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Eu gostaria de saber como posso colocar os campos CODIGO_PROCESSO, NOME_PRODUTO_PROCESSO e APROVADO_USO no select principal para mostrar na minha consulta

```
SELECT CODIGO_PROCESSO,
MAX (DECODE (tipo_arquivo, 'BT', caminho_arquivo)) ArquivoBT, 
MAX (DECODE (tipo_arquivo, 'FC', caminho_arquivo)) ArquivoFC, 
MAX (DECODE (tipo_arquivo, 'MS', caminho_arquivo)) ArquivoMS 
FROM (SELECT PQA.CODIGO_PROCESSO, PQN.NOME_PRODUTO_PROCESSO, PQN.APROVADO_USO, PQA.TIPO_ARQUIVO, PQA.CAMINHO_ARQUIVO FROM PQAQ PQA, PQIN PQN WHERE (PQA.CODIGO_PROCESSO = PQN.CODIGO_PROCESSO) AND (PQN.CODIGO_PROCESSO = 22))
GROUP BY CODIGO_PROCESSO
```

Answer (score 2):

Sem entra no mérito do motivo do subselect

```
SELECT  CODIGO_PROCESSO, 
        NOME_PRODUTO_PROCESSO, 
        PROVADO_USO,
        MAX (DECODE (tipo_arquivo, 'BT', caminho_arquivo)) ArquivoBT, 
        MAX (DECODE (tipo_arquivo, 'FC', caminho_arquivo)) ArquivoFC, 
        MAX (DECODE (tipo_arquivo, 'MS', caminho_arquivo)) ArquivoMS 
FROM (SELECT PQA.CODIGO_PROCESSO, 
             PQN.NOME_PRODUTO_PROCESSO, 
             PQN.APROVADO_USO, 
             PQA.TIPO_ARQUIVO, 
             PQA.CAMINHO_ARQUIVO 
      FROM PQAQ PQA, PQIN PQN 
      WHERE (PQA.CODIGO_PROCESSO = PQN.CODIGO_PROCESSO) 
      AND (PQN.CODIGO_PROCESSO = 22))
GROUP BY CODIGO_PROCESSO, 
        NOME_PRODUTO_PROCESSO, 
        PROVADO_USO
```

Comment: Funciou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.